# Windows 2008 server Powershell Active Directory -> Get user creation date

Tags: windows, powershell, server

i just need a list of all AD users and their creation date.
Something like this:

Julian Ross: 2020-02-01
Mark Lenders: 2019-03-03
Oliver Hutton: 2018-03-01

Ordered by creation date descending.

Is it possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * | Sort-Object whenCreated -Descending | ForEach {
  "$($_.samAccountName): $($_.whenCreated)"
}
```

Comment: This solution does not sort.